# How to reshape data with summary statistics?

Tags: r

I'm conducting a survey and would like to reshape my data to provide specific summary statistics on responses to a given question by a given group *without* manually creating fields. (The number of questions I'll be handling would make this prohibitive.)

Currently, this is what I have:

```
library(reshape2)

test.0 <- read.csv("test.csv")

test.1 <- dcast(
    test.0,
    school+year~questionnaire+question+answer+answer.code
    )

test.2 <- melt.data.frame(
    test.1,
    id.vars = c(school, year),
    variable.names = c("questionnaire", "question", "answer", "answer.code"),
    factorsAsStrings = TRUE
    )
```

The `dcast` function will reshape the data into columns, but I can't figure out what to add to get it to do calculations and add columns automatically. (I was thinking I could `melt` the data frame, run calculations, and recast it, but I'm having trouble melting.

For each question, I would like to calculate (short hand, not code):

1. *The number of responses with each answer option (count if school = a, year = b, question = c, answer = d)
2. The total number of responses (sum answer != "DNA")
3. *The percent of responses with each answer option (count if answer = d / sum answer != "DNA)
4. The percent response rate (sum answer != c("NULL", "DNA") / sum answer != c("DNA"))
5. The average response as a score (sum question.code / count answer != c("NULL", "DNA"))

*May require multiple columns, one for each response option

Here is a sample data set (NULL = Student did not answer, DNA = I did not ask):

```
studentid    year    school      questionnaire   question    answer      answer-code 
517202  2018     High School    1    Do you like ice cream?      Yes    5
553908  2017     High School    1    Do you like ice cream?      No     1
424835  2019     High School    1    Do you like ice cream?      Yes    5
471321  2024     Middle School  1    Do you like ice cream?      No     1
458237  2021     Middle School  1    Do you like ice cream?      No     1
300763  2024     Middle School  1    Do you like ice cream?      NULL    NULL 
173314  2018     High School    1    Do you like ice cream?      NULL    NULL 
924930  2023     Middle School  1    Do you like ice cream?      Yes    5
902908  2019     High School    1    Do you like ice cream?      No     1
227533  2018     High School    1    Do you like ice cream?      No     1
517202  2018     High School    1    Do you like ice cream sundaes?      Yes    5
553908  2017     High School    1    Do you like ice cream sundaes?      No     1
424835  2019     High School    1    Do you like ice cream sundaes?      Yes    5
471321  2024     Middle School  1    Do you like ice cream sundaes?      No     1
458237  2021     Middle School  1    Do you like ice cream sundaes?      No     1
300763  2024     Middle School  1    Do you like ice cream sundaes?      DNA     DNA 
173314  2018     High School    1    Do you like ice cream sundaes?      DNA     DNA 
924930  2023     Middle School  1    Do you like ice cream sundaes?      Yes    5
902908  2019     High School    1    Do you like ice cream sundaes?      NULL    NULL 
227533  2018     High School    1    Do you like ice cream sundaes?      No     1
517202  2018     High School    2    The ice cream party made me like ice cream more.    Neither Agree nor Disagree     3
553908  2017     High School    2    The ice cream party made me like ice cream more.    Agree  4
424835  2019     High School    2    The ice cream party made me like ice cream more.    Disagree   2
471321  2024     Middle School  2    The ice cream party made me like ice cream more.    Strongly Agree     5
458237  2021     Middle School  2    The ice cream party made me like ice cream more.    Disagree   2
300763  2024     Middle School  2    The ice cream party made me like ice cream more.    Agree  3
173314  2018     High School    2    The ice cream party made me like ice cream more.    Strongly Disagree  1
924930  2023     Middle School  2    The ice cream party made me like ice cream more.    Neither Agree nor Disagree     3
902908  2019     High School    2    The ice cream party made me like ice cream more.    Agree  4
227533  2018     High School    2    The ice cream party made me like ice cream more.    NULL    NULL
```

Here is the data frame I would like to end up with (except repeating columns 2-8 for the other questions in columns 9+):

```
school | year | 1_Do you like ice cream?_#Yes | 1_Do you like ice cream?_#No | 1_Do you like ice cream?_#NULL | 1_Do you like ice cream?_#Total | 1_Do you like ice cream?_%Yes | 1_Do you like ice cream?_%No | 1_Do you like ice cream?_Response Rate | 1_Do you like ice cream?_Ice Cream Score**
High School | 2017 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1
High School | 2018 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 0.333333333 | 0.333333333 | 0.666666667 | 2
High School | 2019 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0.5 | 0.5 | 1 | 3
High School | 2020 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
Middle School | 2021 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 
Middle School | 2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 
Middle School | 2023 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 5 
Middle School | 2024 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0.5 | 0.5 | 1
```

Is there a simpler solution? Am I at least on the right track? Any guidance would be super appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at the dplyr package which is made for this purpose

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It looks like some combination of `mutate` and `summaries` will allow me to do this. I'm still pretty new to R, so it will take a bit of reading and trial and error to sort it out. Do you have any suggestions on an order of operations?